# VBA Excel: Assigning range values to a new range

Tags: vba, excel, cells, range

I am having trouble assigning values from one workbook range to a range in my current workbook. When I assign my range using Range("A1:C1") this code works fine, however when my range is defined using Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,3)) the function fails:

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Dim inputExcel As Excel.Application, BookA As Workbook
    Path_A = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Book_A.xlsx"
    Set inputExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set BookA = inputExcel.Workbooks.Open(Path_A, ReadOnly:=True)

    'THIS WORKS:
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C1").Value = _
    BookA.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C1").Value

    'THIS DOESN'T WORK:
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Value = _
    BookA.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Value
End Sub
```

I know this must be a simple syntax issue but I haven't been able to figure it out. How can I get the Range assignments using "Cells" to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you've gotta qualify the Cells calls with a worksheet object too:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3)).Value = _
    BookA.Sheets(1).Range(BookA.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), BookA.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3)).Value
```

for contiguous ranges like that you can also use Resize:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = _
        BookA.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 3).Value
```

Comment: No you don't, and this doesn't solve the problem anyways because `Sheet1.Cells(1,1)` evaluats to a *string*, not an address or range object.  :)

Comment: yes you do, and no it doesn't - try it and see :-) this is a pretty standard method

Comment: Your second method should work, I think.  But the first method, this raises a 1004 for me: 
`Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1)).Value = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)).Value`

Comment: that's not my method - you need *two* cells if you pass Range objects to the Range property: a start cell and an end cell. there wouldn't be much point using Range and Cells together for one cell ;-)

Comment: You're right. Lazy debugging on my part. I sitll think it's a horribly cumbersome way of working with multiple objects, though :)

Comment: I prefer the second method, of the two you offer. I think the range `Resize` and `Offset` methods are under-utilized by most people.

Comment: it is but sometimes it is the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

I think ultimately you are going about this in not the best way to solve the problem.  You have `object.object.object.object` notation in your code, which is cumbersome and hard to interpret and fix.

If you define some more variables, the code will be easier to troubleshoot and solve your problem:

```
Dim myAddr as String 'A string to represent the Address of the range
myAddr = Cells(1,1).Address & ":" & Cells(1,3).Address

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(myAddr).Value = BookA.Sheets(1).Range(myAddr).Value
```

Comment: Although I'm sure that your answer will work, I'm not sure if I agree with the remark. When debugging larger VBA projects, I'm usually in favor of using the namespaces in all statements to avoid confusion about the current object. Especially when working cross-workbook or cross-application, it will reduce the number of errors made and I actually find it easier to debug.

Comment: @KimGysen in the real world I use `With` blocks and define object variables where appropriate (e.g., `Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A50")`, etc.) and I use the `Locals` window to assist debugging.  But, YMMV. :)