# Consolidate Paste Special (Values)

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

How can the data copied to the consolidated sheet be pasted as values, currently works but where formulas are present these are copied over as is when in fact its the result needed from the initial sheet that needs to be taken.

An additional mod is also needed to only copy from row 2 on each entry sheet to the consolidated data tab.

```
Sub Consolidate_Data_From_Different_Sheets_Into_Single_Sheet()

On Error GoTo IfError

Dim Sht As Worksheet, DstSht As Worksheet
Dim LstRow As Long, LstCol As Long, DstRow As Long
Dim i As Integer, EnRange As String
Dim SrcRng As Range

With Application
 .ScreenUpdating = False
 .EnableEvents = False
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidate_Data").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

With ActiveWorkbook
 Set DstSht = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
 DstSht.Name = "Consolidate_Data"
End With

For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Sht.Name <> DstSht.Name Then

        DstRow = fn_LastRow(DstSht)     

        LstRow = fn_LastRow(Sht)
        LstCol = fn_LastColumn(Sht)
        EnRange = Sht.Cells(LstRow, LstCol).Address
        Set SrcRng = Sht.Range("A1:" & EnRange)

        If DstRow + SrcRng.Rows.Count > DstSht.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "There are not enough rows to place the data in the Consolidate_Data worksheet."
            GoTo IfError
        End If

        SrcRng.Copy Destination:=DstSht.Range("A" & DstRow + 1)

    End If

Next

DstSht.Range("A1") = "X"

IfError:
    With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = True
     .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub

Function fn_LastRow(Sht As Worksheet)

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
lRow = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
Do While Application.CountA(Sht.Rows(lRow)) = 0 And lRow <> 1
    lRow = lRow - 1
Loop
fn_LastRow = lRow

End Function

Function fn_LastColumn(Sht As Worksheet)

Dim lastCol As Long
lastCol = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
lCol = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
Do While Application.CountA(Sht.Columns(lCol)) = 0 And lCol <> 1
    lCol = lCol - 1
Loop
fn_LastColumn = lCol

End Function
```

Tried adding:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: `pasted as values` If you don't need formatting, don't copy paste. Set ranges to each other.

Comment: Change this line `SrcRng.Copy Destination:=DstSht.Range("A" & DstRow + 1)`  to `DstSht.Range("A" & DstRow + 1).Resize(SrcRng.Rows,SrcRng.Columns).Value = SrcRng.Value`  As @findwindow stated it will assign the value and will be quicker than the copy paste.

Comment: @ScottCraner This now fails to transfer the information from existing sheets to the consolidated sheet after the amendment. On running no data is moved over,  suggestions please? Need also just to take from row two down on each data sheet.

Comment: @findwindow could you give an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637835/vba-excel-assigning-range-values-to-a-new-range

Comment: @findwindow sorry don't get it, could you offer an amendment to the code I've included above please?

Comment: .... what part don't you get? Did you even write the code above?